# If $Re(f)$ is a polynomial then $f$ is a polynomial, where$f$ is entire

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, entire-functions

If $f$ is entire, and $Re(f)$ is a polynomial in x,y I am trying to show that f is a polynomial in z.

We can write $f(z) = u(z) + iv(z)$. where $Re(f) = u(z)$

I have solved problems similar to this one before, except usually the real part is bounded which allows me to use Liouville's theorem, here since there is no such condition I am unsure of how to proceed.

I also know that since v is the harmonic conjugate of u, it is uniquely determined up to addition of a constant, I believe this fact is helpful but not sure how to begin with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ can be written as power series $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ with radius of convergence = $\infty$. If $f$ is not a polynomial, then neccessarily infinitely many $a_n \ne 0$. In that case $Re(f)$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: "In that case Re(f) is not a polynomial." This maybe so, but why?

Comment: Write $a_n = r_n + i s_n$, $r_n, s_n \in \mathbb{R}$. If $a_n \ne 0$, then $r_n \ne 0$ or $s_n \ne 0$. But then $Re(f)$ contains a term $r_n x^n$ and a term $-n s_n x^{n-1}y$. Therefore, if infinitely many $a_n \ne 0$, then $Re(f)$ is obviously not a polynomial.